# Can't popen new instance of python.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, popen

There’s a project where I need to use both Python 3.3 and 2.7. I am trying to launch a script under Python 2.7 but it’s not working. Here is a simple example.

**first.py**

```
import subprocess
import sys
print('Inside first.py')
print(sys.version)
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\Python.exe", "second.py"])
```

**second.py**

```
import arcpy

print 'This is second.py'
```

This doesn’t work and the output is

```
Inside first.py
3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site.py", line 173
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That’s the entire stack trace. If I were to replace `C:\...Python.exe` with `notepad.exe` then it works. I’m using Liclipse on Windows 7.

UPDATE: it appears different versions of Python are run, when from the command line `python first.py` is 3.3 but `py first.py` or just `first.py` then 2.7 is used.

Comment: As I said yesterday in the comment to (now deleted?) duplicate question: (1) run the simplest possible python 2 script first i.e., remove `import arcpy` from `second.py` and see whether it works (2) put `import sys; print sys.version` (no parentheses!) into `second.py` and run. If you see Python 3 instead of Python 2 then *find out why `C:\Python27` folder (suggests Python _2.7_ version) contains python _3_ executable.* (3) run `first.py` from the command line (cmd.exe), to get the full traceback

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it depends how I run it. `python first.py` results in `second.py` being run as 2.7 but `py first.py` and just `first.py` result in `second.py` being run as 3.3. And if I try to run from Eclipse it just crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import os
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.2\\Python.exe", "second.py"], env=dict(os.environ, PYTHONHOME="C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.2"))
```

Python on Windows needs a little help sometimes to figure out which version of the standard library to use.

Comment: Thanks for the try but now it gives `File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\lib\subprocess.py", line 660, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
`

Comment: Wahohahahah0oh hoa it worked!!! Good job @kirbyfan64sos this really means a lot to us!

Comment: @Celeritas In my edit? I forgot the keyword argument specifier `env=`, so I ended up passing the environment to the buffer size by accident. :/

Comment: I'm wondering why is it necessary to set the PYTHONHOME, because it seems that would effect the parent process but not the child (and the child is opened using the python.exe for 2.7)?

Comment: @Celeritas I believe Python stores the location of the standard library in the registry. For some (stupid) reason, when you install Python 2 *and* 3, the libraries will conflict, causing Python 2 to read 3's library location and end up loading Python 3 modules instead of the Python 2 ones. The `env` argument to `Popen` allows to to set environment variables in the child process. Here, I used it to set `PYTHONHOME` to the proper standard library folder.

Comment: Unfortunatly I spoke to soon. I accidentally ran it from Python 2.7, the first needs to be run from Python 3.3. I still get the error `File "C:\Python33\lib\site.py", line 173
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Celeritas Where is the `Lib` directory located within `C:\Python27`?

Comment: C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\Lib. But hold on a second it appears to work when I launch it manually from cmd with `python first.py` instead of using Eclipse.

Comment: When I launch from the command line if I do `python first.py` then the first.py runs as 3.3 and second runs as 2.7. BUT if I do `py first.py` or just `fist.py` then both first.py and second.py run as 2.7 (bad). I'm using `print(sys.version)` to determine what it's running under.